# Making small additions to an existing wxPython control

Tags: python, inheritance, wxpython, super

I'm trying to get the behaviour of an existing wxPython control and simply draw some graphics over that.

The code below shows my current attempt. If I instantiate a `StaticTextUnderline` rather than a `wx.StaticText`, it behaves perfectly, with the former acting exactly like the latter. In other words, the exact same text showing up inside the control (a 20-line-by-20-character textual piece of drivel):

```py
import wx

class StaticTextUnderline(wx.StaticText): 
    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        super(StaticTextUnderline, self).__init__(parent, *args)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        
    def OnPaint(self, e):
        super(StaticTextUnderline, self).Update()
        # dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        # pen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(255,0,0))
        # pen.SetWidth(1)
        # dc.SetPen(pen) 
        # dc.DrawLine(0, 0, 50, 50)
```

The commented code is meant to simply draw a red line over the text after the static text has been painted. Unfortunately, the *instant* I uncomment the first of those lines, the control no longer renders the text. I *suspect* getting another device context may be clearing the current content. If I uncomment all of it, I get the red line but that's no good to me if the underlying static text has been cleared somehow.

How can I intercept an arbitrary `wxPython` control and just fiddle with the content after it has done its work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it *looks* like the original thoughts (that the second paint device context may be causing the issue) are correct. After originally trying to figure out how to get *one* context and use it both for the superclass call and the `OnPaint` calls, it turns out that you can do this simply by getting a different type of device context (a client one).

There are warnings in the documentation about using a non-paint context in the paint event (and a paint context outside of a paint event) but I suspect this just has to do with the *first* context obtained.

So the following code appears to work, rendering both the underlying text *and* the red line:

```py
def OnPaint(self, e):
    super(StaticTextUnderline, self).Update()
    dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
    pen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(255,0,0))
    pen.SetWidth(1)
    dc.SetPen(pen) 
    dc.DrawLine(0, 0, 50, 50)
```

Comment: Can you provide a worked example. I'm not getting your results on Linux with wxPython 4.1.1 and this function could be useful. Strikethough could operate in the same way.